# Bash: Grep Line Numbers to Correspond to AWK NR

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I suspect I am going around this the long way but please bear with me I am new to Bash, grep and awk ...

The summary of my problem is that line numbers in grep do no correspond to the actual line numbers in a file. From what I gather empty lines are discarded in the line numbering. I would prefer not to iterate through every line in a file to ensure 100% coverage.

What I am trying to do is grab a segment of lines from a file and process them using grep and awk

1. The grep call gets a list of line numbers since there could be more than one instance of a 'starting position' in a file:

   `startLnPOSs=($(cat "$c"| grep -e '^[^#]' | grep --label=root -e '^[[:space:]]start-pattern' -n -T | awk '{print $1}'`
2. Then using awk I iterate from a starting point until an 'end' token is encountered.

   `declarations=($(cat "$c" | awk "$startLnPos;/end-pattern/{exit}" ))`

Comment: `grep` doesn't ignore blank lines in its numbering.

Comment: You could do the whole thing in awk. Also look up how to use shell variables in awk.

Comment: Why are you using `grep` to find the starting line numbers? You can match the same pattern in `awk`.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I figured .. back to the drawing board. I am going to close this.

Comment: @Barmar, like I said I am new to this .. I guessed that awk was the way to go .. I will need to look around a little more. 

As for grep returning the correct line numbers that's not really what I am seeing. I am processing an Apache conf file and both nano and emacs are reporting the second instance of starting token on ln 31 but grep is reporting ln 26. There are 5 'blank' lines between the start of the file and the second instance of the starting token. This is why my assumption is that the grep line numbers ignores an empty line. 

Any ideas?

Comment: `grep -e '^[^#]'` is filtering out the blank lines.

Comment: It also filters out comment lines. In both cases, that causes the line numbers to change.

Comment: There's no need for that first `grep`, since the pattern in the second grep won't match comment lines.

Comment: edit  your Q to show small sample input data and  your expected output, with your current output, error messages. Agree with all above. Maybe you want to spend a hour on http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks a bit like an xy problem as you are showing us what you are doing to solve a problem but not actually outlining the problem.

So on a guess I am thinking you want to return all the items between the start/end patterns to your array (which may also be erroneous, but again we do not know the overall picture).

So what you could do is:

```
declarations=($(awk '/start-pattern/,/end-pattern/' "$c"))
```

Or with sed (exactly the same):

```
declarations=($(sed -n '/start-pattern/,/end-pattern/p' "$c"))
```

Depending if you want those actual lines included or not the commands may need to be altered a little.

Was this the kind of thing you were looking to do??

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for .. thank you.